# "This problem of his" - rephrasings?

Tags: passive-voice

What other ways can this be phrased? This doesn't even sound right to me. How do you put a possessive-passive sentence properly. Quite confused for some reason.

Comment: Why not just "his problem"?

Answer (score 2):

"This [thing] of mine/his/hers/theirs/yours/ours" is perfectly normal and acceptable. There is nothing "not right" about it.

> Possessives with of
>
> Noun phrase + of + possessive pronoun
>
> We can talk about possession using the pattern: noun phrase + of +
>   possessive pronoun:
>
> A friend of mine told me that all of the tickets have already sold
>   out.
>
> Where’s Martin? He’s gone to pick up a cousin of his at the station.
>
> Is Linda McGrath a close friend of yours?

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine

Comment: I wonder why I got a downvote?

Comment: I do to.  I find this forum has lots of downvotes compared to others, often when the questioner is struggling with something that others do also, and they empathize.  I upvoted your answer.  One could also just say “his problem” if “this problem of his” sounds awkward.   I suspect the question is looking for a better solution in “Globish”, not English.

Comment: I don't believe in downvotes unless something is clearly nonsensical, invalid, or completely off topic. If I agree with something, I upvote it. Otherwise, I leave it alone. I believe downvotes should only be used for grievous mistakes. I further believe that most downvotes should be accompanied by the person leaving a comment that explains their response. Have an upvote. :)